# How do I export a Gantt Chart from MS Project to MS Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project, gantt-chart

Using MS Project 2003 i want to export the "View | Gantt Chart" to MS Word (2000) using VBA.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you want to do with it once it is in Word?  Are you going to just print it?  Or edit it?

Answer (score 2):

In Project, Use Edit, Copy Picture.
there's a camera icon on the standard toolbar (the top one) ... you can take
a "photo" of your gantt chart and use that in word 
Version 2003 also has a Wizard for this export HTH
I always select the task rows and then when using the "camera" select
the option of selected tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Copy Picture object model calls.  You can either output to the clipboard or save a .gif.